# Constant Password Checking?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have read on stackoverflow the following:

```
never store the users password or even a hash of the password in session or cookie data.
```

I'm in the middle of making a system to check for a constant password, if it's different from one saved in a session, then force a logout; something like facebook does? When you change your password, or a password has been changed, you get logged out.

My code follows below:

```
function ConstantPassword($Password)
{
    if ($_SESSION['Password'] !== $Password)
    {
        include "Logout.php";
    }
}
```

But, If it's said not to store passwords in a session/cookie? What could be another workaround for this?

Comment: i have read, that the moon is made of green cheeses.

Comment: @Dagon so your saying it's alright to store passwords in a browser session?

Comment: then you would just be blindly following some other comment read on the internet.

Comment: What is the purpose of this "constant password"?

Comment: @NullUserException I want to integrate something like facebook does; enforcing a Logout when a password doesn't match, or even changed; just alerting users (that might have their account hacked into) that a password has been changed

Comment: When a user is logged in, *you* have to keep track of their session on the server side. You can just invalidate this session on the server side whenever the password has been changed.

Comment: @NullUserException store the user password as `$StoredPassword = $Password; $UserPass = $Password; unset($Password);`  something like that?

Comment: @user1968541 I mean, you are keeping track of the user's session somewhere in your SQL database, right? You aren't just creating a PHP session and leaving it at that, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the check once, and then store a `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE` variable. On logging out, you `unset($_SESSION['logged_in'])` it and `session_destroy()` the session. No need to put the password nor the salt in the session.

Also, you should not implement passwords on your own but instead, use this: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat It's the library that's going to be in PHP 5.5.

Comment: I assume the question is related to invalidating **all** active sessions of the user upon changing his password, so this method probably won't be enough. Let @user1968541 decide...

Answer (score 1):

You could store the salt (or a hash thereof) in the session.

Changing the password should change the salt, which will then invalidate the session.

Comment: I don't have that much experience when integrating salt into passwords, I know I should not do it.. But the password is stored with the broken MD5

Comment: no store a session variable that just lets you know whether they logged in or not. do not store any password info. there is no need. see answer by @rygu

Comment: @nathanhayfield: what if a user has multiple active sessions? This won't invalidate them all...

Comment: why would you allow a user to have multiple log in sessions?

Comment: @nathanhayfield: Multiple browsers or computers.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: You're misunderstanding my answer.  He needs to invalidate prior sessions when they're next used.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the password once than store in the database a pair (random_hash,user_id) and put the random_hash in the session.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid storing the password in the session, you could store the **timestamp of the last password change** instead and validate it against the database on every request.

Comment: how can you authenticate a user by means of a timestamp?

Comment: Since the question is about forcing a logoff on password change, I assumed the user was already authenticated and the question is only about checking whether the password had been changed in the meantime.